# Adding an element to objects in array of objects Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

The problem is very simple. I tried many times thus I came for help in stackoverflow.
I have an array of object called data which is a returned data from mongodb database.
Formatted similar as:

```
 let data = [
{ booking: [ ref], max_booking: 0 },
{ booking: [ref], max_booking: 3 },
{ booking: [ref], max_booking: 5 },
{booking: [ref], max_booking: 4}
];
```

With request I added real data coming from my db:

```
[ { booking: [],
_id: null,
__v: 0,
comment: 'this is a comment',
date: 2020-07-26T00:00:00.000Z,
event_detail: 'this is event detail',
location: 'Kthm',
max_booking: 5,
meal_option: [ [Object] ],
sponsor_address: 'xxxx',
sponsor_name: 'yyyy',
id: null },
{ booking: [],
_id: 5ef60fab6c164281aee9ae2e,
date: 2020-07-30T00:00:00.000Z,
location: 'Kthm',
comment: 'this is another',
sponsor_name: 'Micorosft',
sponsor_address: 'USA',
event_detail: 'this is event detail',
meal_option: [ [Object] ],
max_booking: 5,
__v: 0,
id: '5ef60fab6c164281aee9ae2e' },
{ booking: [],
_id: 5ef6131f6c164281aee9ae30,
date: 2020-07-30T00:00:00.000Z,
location: 'TAN TOCK SENG HOSPITAL',
comment: 'this is dsadasdas',
sponsor_name: 'Asus',
sponsor_address: 'Los Angeles, USAssadsad',
event_detail: 'this is event detail',
meal_option: [ [Object] ],
max_booking: 5,
__v: 0,
id: '5ef6131f6c164281aee9ae30' },

]
```

I want to perform a operation as like:
When max_booking is matched with length of booking array on any object, a new element should be added to that specific object as like.

```
{booking:[lets assume 5], max_booking: 5, result:1}
```

If in case the booking is still less than also a new element should be added but with result as 0 like

```
{booking:[lets asssume 3], max_booking:5, result:0}
```

To perform this operation I did was:

```
    data.map((d, i) => {
     if (d.booking.length === d.max_booking) {
      console.log("Fully Booked in index", i);
       d.result = 1;
     } else {
       console.log("Not booked");
       d.result = 0;
      }
      console.log(d.result);
    });
  console.log(data[3]);
```

Lets ignore else for now should be less than sign.
The value of d.result inside the foreach loop is printed on console but when I log the data, no thing is changed at all.
Can anyone help me with it. Thanks in advance.

Screenshot of code:
[image]

Screenshot of output:
[image: Output]

Comment: are you logging `data` after the map? or are you logging the result of `data.map(...)`?

Comment: If you're not interested in the return value of `.map()` then you shouldn't be using it. You want `.forEach()`

Comment: @richytong I logged value of data[4] for testing what comes the result. I have edited question

Comment: Your array only has four elements, hence the last index is `3` not `4`. That said... Your script works: https://jsfiddle.net/3x9cadr1/ (but please replace `.map()` with `.forEach()`

Comment: @Andreas I have large data but I have formatted similar as I have written in question. I tried forEach() too. The result appears same

Comment: As you can see on my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3x9cadr1/) your script in the question works. Therefor this is not the script your using -> Please add a [mcve] that shows the actual problem (preferable as executable snippet)

Comment: Are you sure the `max_booking` is a number and not a string in your actual data?

Comment: @slappy I am very sure it's a number.

Comment: @Andreas please have a look at my real dataset on question. I have added it

Comment: And a third time... Your script (at least the version in this question) works: https://jsfiddle.net/3x9cadr1/ - If your actual script doesn't then you haven't shown as that actual script.

Comment: @Bibek what are you using this transformation for?

Comment: @Andreas I know the script works well on jsfiddle. This is really my actual script. I am adding the screenshots of my code and output  too.

Comment: Try checking if `data[3]` is frozen, like this: `console.log(Object.isFrozen(data[3]));`

Answer (score 0):

why people are moving away a simple for loop ?

```
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
     if (data[i].booking.length === data[i].max_booking) {
       console.log("Fully Booked in index", i);
       data[i].result = 1;
     } else {
       console.log("Not booked");
       data[i].result = 0;
     }
}
console.log(data.result);
```

Comment: for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
     data[i].result = (data[i].booking.length === data[i].max_booking) * 1;
}
console.log(data.result);

Comment: Doesn't explain the OP's result though. Even using (or misusing) `map()`, it should do the same thing as yours.

Answer (score 0):

Because map() [return a new array](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp), if you change data inside map(), you should get back your new array like this:

```
var data = [{a:1},{a:2}]
data = data.map((d,i)=>{d.a = d.a+1; return d})

// Array [2]
// 0: Object { a: 2 }
​// 1: Object { a: 3 }
​
```

Comment: Shouldn't matter when you're mutating the objects anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're forgetting to return `d` from inside your map. You have to return from the `map` callback to get the new array.

```js
const data = [
  { booking: [], max_booking: 0 },
  { booking: [{}, {}, {}], max_booking: 3 },
  { booking: [], max_booking: 5 },
  { booking: [{}, {}, {}], max_booking: 4 },
]

const mapped = data.map((d, i) => {
  if (d.booking.length === d.max_booking) {
    console.log("Fully Booked in index", i);
    d.result = 1;
  } else {
    console.log("Not booked");
    d.result = 0;
  }
  console.log(d.result);
  return d
})

console.log(mapped)
```

Comment: OP doesn't use the return value at all hence it is not relevant that OP isn't returning anything from the callback. The objects are modified "in-place" and OPs script works.